# No Input transmission after file transfer - Socket

Tags: java, c, sockets, file-upload

I am creating a file transfer through sockets. My client is in Java and my server is in C. I am able to acknowledge the connection between client and server and send the file name also to server. The file is also getting created at server side but the server is not able to get EOF and so gets stuck in the loop. Because of this, there is no data transmission after file transfer. My relevant client and server code is below. Please guide/correct me how to achieve this.

**Server in C**

```
    int connfd;
    int n;
    char buffer[3000];
    FILE *fp;
    int result;
    char *message = "";

    n = recv(connfd, buffer, sizeof buffer, 0); //connfd is my created socket

    if ( n > 0 )
    {
        fprintf(stdout,"Received %d bytes\n", n);
        fprintf(stdout,"Received Data: %s",buffer);
        buffer[strlen(buffer)-1] = '\0';

        if(strcmp(buffer, "incoming_file"))
        {
            fprintf(stdout, "client: incoming file");
            message="send data\n";
            result = send(connfd , message , strlen(message) , 0);

            if(result == SOCKET_ERROR)
                printf("send failed with error codfe %d\n",WSAGetLastError());

            else
                fprintf(stdout,"\nsent %d bytes out of %u \n",result,strlen(message));

        }

        else
        {
            fprintf(stdout,"invalid data received");
            return NULL;
        }

        n = recv(connfd, buffer, sizeof buffer, 0);

        if(n > 0)
        {
            fprintf(stdout, "Received %d bytes\n", n);
            fprintf(stdout,"Received Data: %s",buffer);

            fp = fopen(buffer, "wb");

            if (fp == NULL)
            {
                printf("File not created!\n");
                return NULL;
            }
            else
            {
                printf("Created file %s\n", buffer);

                message="file created\n";
                result = send(connfd , message , strlen(message) , 0);

                if(result == SOCKET_ERROR)
                    printf("send failed with error codfe %d\n",WSAGetLastError());
                else
                    fprintf(stdout,"\nsent %d bytes out of %u \n",result,strlen(message));

                while ((n = recv(connfd, buffer, sizeof buffer, 0)) > 0)
                {
                    fwrite(buffer, sizeof(char), n, fp);
                    fprintf(stdout, "Received %d bytes\n", n);
                }   //gets stuck in this loop

                printf("\n after while"); // control never comes here

                message="file uploaded\n";
                result = send(connfd , message , strlen(message) , 0);

                if(result == SOCKET_ERROR)
                    printf("send failed with error codfe %d\n",WSAGetLastError());
                else
                    fprintf(stdout,"\nsent %d bytes out of %u \n",result,strlen(message));
            }
        }

        else
        {
            fprintf(stdout,"filename not received");
        }
    }

    else
    {
        fprintf(stdout,"no data received");
    }

    printf("client disconnected from);
    getchar();
    closesocket(connfd);
    WSACleanup();
    return 0;
}
```

**Client in Java**

```
            File file = new File("C:/Data/.../Picture1.jpg");
            byte[] bytes = new byte[3000];
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
            BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
            BufferedReader input =  new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
            OutputStream out = socket.getOutputStream();

            int count;
            out.write(("incoming_file"+"\0").getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8")));

            String st;
            int i = 0;
            while((st = input.readLine()) != null)
            {
                switch (st)
                {
                case "send data":
                    System.out.println("data: "+st);
                    System.out.println("File name: "+file.getName().trim());
                    out.write((file.getName()+"\0").getBytes("UTF-8"));
                    out.flush();

                    break;

                case "file created":
                    System.out.println("data: "+st);

                    while ((count = bis.read(bytes)) > 0) 
                    {
                        System.out.println(count);
                        out.write(bytes, 0, count);
                    }

                    out.flush();
                    fis.close();
                    bis.close();

                    System.out.println("file sending complete"); //this gets printed

                    break;

                case "file uploaded":   //never comes here
                    System.out.println("data: "+st);
                    break;

                default:
                        System.out.println("in default: "+st);
                        break;
                }
                System.out.println(i++);
            }

            out.flush();
            out.close();
            input.close();
        }  

        catch(IOException ioe)
        {
            System.out.println("Exception during communication. Server closed connection.");
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }

        finally
        {
            try
            {
                // Close the socket before quitting
                socket.close();
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }                
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
this line from the man page for recv() contains the answer:

" If  no messages are available at the socket, the receive calls wait for
   a message to arrive,"

a MUCH better method is to code a select() (with timeout)/recv() loop.

Then when a timeout occurs, the file transfer is completed.
remember to refresh time timeout value each time through the loop.
use a reasonable timeout, say 1 second, to allow for 
network and similar delays.

I.E.
while(forever)
    // refresh timeout value
    // result = select(...) 
    // note: result value: 0 == timeout, <0 == error, >0 == data received
    // if 0 < result
    // then, recv()
    // else exit loop
end while
// if 0==result
// then all ok
// else if 0 > result
// then handle error
// endif
```

Comment: That is not an answer to OP question.  It's a redesign.

Answer (score 0):

You need a more sophisticated protocol.  It is not, in general, possible to passively determine when the remote machine has closed the connection or stopped transmitting data.

One way to approach the end-of-transmission problem would be for the client to send the size of the file before the file itself -- then when the server receives that many bytes it knows it has the whole file.  Another way would be to wrap the file in a format with recognizable boundaries, such as a MIME or SOAP envelope.

Even so, is possible for the client to fail or be disconnected mid-transmission, so for a robust server you will want to use `select()` with a timeout to prevent trying to perform a read that is destined to block forever.